# Binding mouse cursor events issue

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having issues with binding events (mouse cursor actions) with StringVar() control variable. A part of the issue is i don't know how to incorporate them all together.

What i would like to do is get names of rectangle shapes i have created and assigned names to.

```
   class GraphicMap(Frame):

      def __init__(self, master = None):
      Frame.__init__(self, master)
      ............## lines of code
      self.content = StringVar()
      self.map.bind(("<Button-1>", self.bind)

     def attrib(self, graphic):
       self.name = graphic  #name i will assign to rectangle shapes

     ................# lines of code
        ## i have created rectangle shapes on a canvas with different 
                     names, using this method.

       ##now i would like to use this method for when i click on a shape, it 
        presents the self.name i have allocated.

      def binding(self, event):
         self.name = event.name
         return event.name

      def setContent(self):
        self.content.set(self.name)
```

As you can see i have not incorporated this properly, it does not compute. Any help on what i can be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you are binding to `self.bind`, but you haven't defined `self.bind`. Since you inherit from `Frame`, `self.bind` is the standard `bind` method